# I am not sure where this question fits, something like "culture?"

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

In England there are Yorkshiremen who know "aught from naught" and in general have the reputation of being hard to fool or cheat. Years ago I wrote to the editors of The New Scientist and asked if Yorkshiremen were anything like Missourians (from The Show Me state) and while they seemed intrigued, I never got an answer.

So, where would I ask this so that someone who knows England and the USA folk culture might see and answer this?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking - "are Yorkshiremen anything like Missourians" - what does that mean? You're trying to understand if Missourians are hard to fool or cheat? Why? What's the connection?

Comment: i am asking where such a question should be asked, irrespective of thoughts about the actual question itself. I don't want to discuss answers to the question in Meta.

Comment: @MarkKirby: Opinions based on works of fiction, etc. This is not a question about genetics or demography although it would be interesting if Missouri had been settled by a large number of people from Yorkshire.

Comment: If we don't understand the question, we can't direct you accurately and if the question type is a poor fit for the platform, directing you at a site where the question may be immediately closed will be a frustrating experience for you.

Answer (score -4):

From a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364693/i-am-not-sure-where-this-question-fits-something-like-culture#comment1217284_364696) to this answer:

> As a moderator on Mythology and Folklore, I agree with @Catija - our scope is really focused on stories and mythological histories, rather than the above question, which . . . seems to be more about stereotypes than folklore in the sense we use. – [HDE 226868](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/274942/hde-226868) *2021-05-21 20:45:24Z, License: CC BY-SA 4.0*

---

Try [Mythology & Folklore](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/)

> Mythology & Folklore Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for enthusiasts and scholars of mythology and folklore.

Tags that might be related to the sample question:

- [folklore](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folklore)

  > For questions on the traditional beliefs, customs and stories of a community or culture.
- [myth-identification](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myth-identification)

  > For questions about identifying a particular myth based on certain known facts or a basic description of its context, characters and events.

Comment: I don't actually see how this question is related to mythology or folklore. The personality types of people living in a region doesn't seem to have anything to do with mythology.

Comment: @Catija did you miss this part  "...where would I ask this so that **someone who knows England and the USA folk culture** might see and answer this?"?

Comment: I did, I still don't see how it relates to that at all. The question doesn't even contain any evidence that what the asker is saying is actually true. Where are the citations that this is a known belief of this culture?

Comment: As a moderator on Mythology and Folklore, I agree with @Catija - our scope is really focused on stories and mythological histories, rather than the above question, which . . . seems to be more about stereotypes than folklore in the sense we use.